# Is there a way to update the Flash player for Google-TV on Logitech Revue?

Tags: adobe-flash, google-tv, logitech-revue

I've noticed any apps that use the Flash player via the browser to play video just fail with a flash error. For example, trying to play a video via Amazon Video On Demand (via the installed App, which just launches the browser on Amazon's web site) results in "The following plug-in has crashed: Shockwave Flash"

Some Flash ads for example work, while other Flash games crash too. I hope there is a way to update Flash and fix this.

- HoneyComb 3.1.0
- [Adobe's Flash Version check](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) shows I have Flash installed.

  - Flash Player Version: 10.2.163.145
  - OS: Linux 2.6.35.14-ge141a01 (32-bit)
  - Capabilities: GTV 10,2,163,145 (Including Audio, Video & Local Files)

[Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer.html) says the latest version of Flash for Android is 11.1.111.8 (Android pre-ICS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Honeycomb 3.2 update for Logitech Review fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you would find one, but you could try sideloading the Flash Player app from the Play Store as installed on another HC 3.1.0 device and see whether that can display Flash content any better.